# DELETE method in Spring boot using Mockito and JUnit

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, junit, mockito

In Spring boot framework, I'm finding a difficulty with the controller Unit testing using JUnit and Mockito. I want to test this method. How to test DELETE Request method:

// delete application **Controller class**

```
    @DeleteMapping("/all")
fun deleteAllApplications(): ResponseEntity<Void?>? {
    applicationService.deleteAllApplications()
    return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

// delete application **Service class**

```
    override fun deleteApplication(appID: String){

     applicationRepository.findById(appID).map { app  ->
        applicationRepository.delete(app)
        ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK)
    }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())


}
```

delete Application **Full Test class**

```kotlin
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class CartoApplicationTests {

    @InjectMocks
    var applicationService: ApplicationServiceImpl? = null

    @Mock
    var applicationRepository: ApplicationRepository? = null

@Test
fun deleteApplicationTest(){
    applicationService?.deleteApplication(appTest.id!!)
    when(applicationRepository?.delete(appTest)){}
}
}
```

**ERROR!**
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr4pW.png)

Thanks for u help

Comment: can you post the full test class

Comment: sure! I have updated the post, thanks for you reply

Comment: you should also mock `applicationRepository.findById()` method